# Why won't my AJAX call insert to the database?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, pdo

I have an ajax function that I'm using to store information in the database. The success message goes off in the console log, but nothing actually gets stored. Any ideas?

If you want me to turn on error messages, please tell me exactly how to do this, and in which file.

AJAX (goes off on a button click)

```
 var id = ranNum;
    //.cart-content is an item inside a shopping cart
    $('.cart-content').each(function() {
        //I know this is not the best way to grab data, but for now it's what I have to do
        var item = $(this).find('.item').text();
        var price = $(this).find('.price').text();

        //These return the proper text, so I'm grabbing the information fine.
        console.log("id: " + id);
        console.log("item: " + item);
        console.log("price: " + price);

        $.ajax({
            url : '../controllers/insertOrder.php',
            //I even added extra letters just in case I couldn't use the same word twice.
            data: {idd: id, itemm: item, pricee: price},
            type : 'POST',
            success : function(){console.log("success");},
            error : errorHandler
        });

    });
```

insertOrder.php (the path is correct)

```
<?php
require_once '../../models/database.php';
require_once 'Order.php';

$order = new Order;
$order->insertOrder($_POST['idd'], $_POST['itemm'], $_POST['pricee']);
```

Order.php

```
class Order{

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function insertOrder ($id, $item, $price) {

        $db = Dbclass::getDB();
        $query = "INSERT INTO orders (order_id, order_item, order_price)
               VALUES(:id, :item, :price)";          

        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $statement->bindParam(':item', $item, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
        $statement->bindParam(':price', $price, PDO::PARAM_STR, 10);

        $statement->execute();

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try echoing out the errors from PDO?

Comment: Try returning a response from the script to ensure it's being hit. I'm unsure if the relative you have specified is viable.

Comment: @trickyzter I get the "success message in my console log that I created for the success method, so it is connecting. I used to have a bad path, then I saw an error in the console log. Now I don't see that error anymore.

Comment: @Machavity I'm not sure I understand how to do that. If you're talking about database.php, I've used that class so many times successfully, so I doubt it is giving me an issue.

Comment: @JordanCarter Try `print_r($statement->errorInfo());` after your `execute()`

Comment: @Machavity tried it, and nothing got printed : (

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. My path to the database in my insertOrder.php file wasn't right. D'oh!

Comment: So this question is totally useless for anyone else. You should delete it.

Comment: @Barmar Are you sure? It explains how to show errors in some of the comments. It show the thought process involved to catch an error like this.